# Precedence of arr[x++]--

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I am confused on how to parse precedence of operations in C. the line

```
countArray[*string++]--
```

Is executing how I want it to, but I don't understand the steps that result in countArray[*string]-- being evaluated before *string++.

My research on C precedence and binding didn't provide answers that relate to this case, and I'm wondering about general rules for post/pre-increment and post/pre-decrement when in combination with other post/pre - crements.

How does C know to evaluate it this way?

```
void discountChars(char* string, char** countArray)
{
    int test;
    while(*string) {
        test = *string;

        //why is countArray[*string]-- evaluated before string++ is incremented?
        countArray[*string++]--;
        printf("countArray[%d] = %d\n", test, countArray[test]);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't program like this. For the sake of other programmers as well as your future self.

Comment: This is not about operator precedence, this is about order of evaluation.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Is the order of evaluation not determined by operator preceedence along with associativity?

Comment: @Olaf no, it isn't. Order of evaluation may depend on precedence and associativity, but those are (let alone precedence only) not sufficient to determine the evaluation order.

Comment: When in doubt, place **one** statement per line. The compiler optimisation will do the rest. It's a fine line between making "fluent" code and fooling the evaluation sequence.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Ok, now I got it. Sorry, I was lost in translation (natural language)!

Comment: More smelly code garbage, unhelpful to future visitors:(  Why is this crap posted day-after-day?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for an explanation of rubbish code that nobody should actually use.

Answer (score 9):

You can break this:

```
    countArray[*string++]--;
```

down into this:

```
    char index = *string;   // get char from `string` into temporary index
    string++;               // increment `string`
    countArray[index]--;    // decrement `countArray` value at given index
```

and then it should be clearer what's going on.

Comment: I am not sure why you use `char index` and not `int index`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: it doesn't really make any difference in this instance, but the promotion from `char` to `int` happens conceptually when the value is used as an array index.

Comment: Only that we don't know the array length, if `[128]` would fail.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `string` is of type `char *` so it can only ever return a `char` when indexed. The `char` value may be signed or unsigned (implementation-defined) and it will then subsequently be promoted to `int`. The implicit range of a `char` still applies though, so the limit to the valid array indices will be `0` to `CHAR_MAX` regardless of when the promotion is applied.

Comment: Yes, but `index` is of type `char`. If that is `signed char` won't a value of `0xFF` will be promoted to an `int` index value of `-1`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: yes, but that would happen regardless of when the promotion takes place. You could use a cast of course, to force the `char` to be treated as `unsigned`, but that's not what the OP's question is about - the code in the answer above behaves identically to the OP's code, and that includes any bugs that might arise from e.g. implicitly signed `char` values > 127.

Answer (score 7):

As it has been stated many times, *precedence* has no connection to the *order of evaluation*. The only thing in C language that can affect order of evaluation is *sequencing*. Precedence has nothing to do with it.

It is also unclear where you got the strange idea that "`countArray[*string]--` is being evaluated before `*string++`". This is simply impossible. The expression in `[]` will always be evaluated first, since its result is required to perform the element access (i.e. sequenced before the element access). Which means that the opposite is true: `*string++` is evaluated before `countArray[*string]--`.

So, the sequence of steps here is

1. Evaluate `*string++`. The result of this expression is the original value of `*string`. Let's designate it `tmp`.

   This expression also "schedules" a side-effect - increment of `string`. But this increment does not have to happen right now.
2. Evaluate `countArray[tmp]--`. The result of this expression is the original value of `countArray[tmp]`. This result is immediately discareded.

   This expression also "schedules" a side-effect - decrement of `countArray[tmp]`. But this decrement does not have to happen right now.
3. Complete the evaluation of the full expression . If any of the above side-effects are still pending, complete them right now.

For example, one possible evaluation schedule might look as follows

```
char tmp = *string; // subexpression inside `[]`
countArray[tmp]; // full expression, result discarded
countArray[tmp] = countArray[tmp] - 1; // side-effect
string = string + 1; // side-effect
```

Another possible evaluation schedule is

```
char tmp = *string; // subexpression inside `[]`
string = string + 1; // side-effect
countArray[tmp]; // full expression, result discarded
countArray[tmp] = countArray[tmp] - 1; // side-effect
```

It can even be evaluated as

```
string = string + 1; // side-effect
char tmp = *(string - 1); // subexpression inside `[]`
countArray[tmp]; // full expression, result discarded
countArray[tmp] = countArray[tmp] - 1; // side-effect
```

Answer (score 1):

Precedence controls groupings of operators and operands, not order of evaluation.

The expression `*string++` *must* be evaluated before it can be used as an array subscript; however, the *side effect* of updating `string` may happen *after* the larger expression has been evaluated.  The following sequence of events is allowed:

```
t1 <- *string
countArray[t1] <- countArray[t1] - 1
string <- string + 1
```

Then again, so is the following:

```
t1 <- *string
string <- string + 1
countArray[t1] <- countArray[t1] - 1
```